# How to limit the pull back length of a slingshot?

Tags: math, box2d

At the moment I have this code which fires a projectile:

```
Vector3 d = mousePos.sub(pouchPos.x, pouchPos.y, 0);
        d.mul(FIRE_SPEED);
        projectile.setVelocity(-d.x, -d.y);
```

Which works fine, and this which sets the position according to the mouse position:

```
turtle.body.setTransform(mousePos.x, mousePos.y, 0);

        if (turtle.pos.dst(pouchPos) > 5)
        {
            //What to put in here?
        }
```

Trouble is I don't know what to put in the `if (turtle.pos.dst(pouchPos) > 5)` clause. What would you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ( length > limit ) 
    vector.mul( limit / length );
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it ends up making the object decrease in its x and y position for some reason.

Comment: Here 'vector' is supposed to be the pull-back vector, not a position.

Comment: I'm not to sure what you mean by "pull-back vector" how would I translate that into the objects position?

Comment: 'Pull-back vector' is the vector from the pull start position to the current touch point, ie. the 'pull back length' mentioned in the title of your question.